# How to add a pie chart to my Access report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table that shows "DONE" and "REMAIN" for each "AREA" like below:

```
 AREA       DONE    REMAIN TOTAL
 AREA1      100     200     300
 AREA2      200     300     500
 AREA3      200     700     900
```

Now I like to make a report that shows "DONE" and "REMAIN" in each AREA with pie chart, now I have problem how I have to do this job for the graph, how should be "row source" of chart control. What query needs on this table?

Comment: Just to be clear: You want three separate pie charts, one for each AREA, correct?

Comment: yes, i want three separate pie charts, one for each AREA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*(I'll assume that your table is named [AREAS].)*

The trick here is to create a saved UNION query named [AreaDataForPieChart]...

```
SELECT "DONE" AS PieCategory, [DONE] AS PieValue, [AREA] FROM [AREAS]
UNION ALL
SELECT "REMAIN" AS PieCategory, [REMAIN] AS PieValue, [AREA] FROM [AREAS]
```

...returning...

```
PieCategory  PieValue  AREA 
-----------  --------  -----
DONE              100  AREA1
DONE              200  AREA2
DONE              200  AREA3
REMAIN            200  AREA1
REMAIN            300  AREA2
REMAIN            700  AREA3
```

...and base the pie chart on that.

Start by creating a Report based on the [AREAS] table, and display [AREA] in a text box:

[image: Report1.png]

Now add a Chart control to the Detail band of the report. When prompted, choose the saved query we created above

[image: ChooseQuery.png]

Choose [PieCategory] and [PieValue] as the columns for the chart

[image: ChooseColumns.png]

Choose "Pie Chart" as the chart type

[image: ChooseChartType.png]

The default data layout will work fine because of the order of the columns in our query

[image: DataLayout.png]

Tell the report to link the chart to the main report by using the [AREA] fields

[image: Linking.png]

Give the chart a meaningful title, then click the "Finish" button.

[image: Finish.png]

Now preview the report. It should look something like this:

[image: Results.png]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link:

A simple way to use pie chart in ms access
I tried with the

```
SELECT status, Count(status) AS count FROM Table1 group by status;
```

Query in Row source of pie chart properties.

The first column will display as a label of the pie chart and 2nd column will display the count.

http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/Access-vba-piechart.htm#