# Access 2010 trying to create pie chart by 1 row data

Tags: ms-access-2010, pie-chart

I have data looks like this

```
Sum Of a | Sum Of b | Sum Of C | Sum Of d
  100    |   200    |    300   |   400
```

In order to create a pie chart I need to change it to format something like this

```
Sum Of |  Value
a      |    x  
c      |    y
d      |    z
```

Question how can I create new table that from the first table by query or any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19327449/1380867) that I found useful on creating chats from ms-access

Here we see that the trick  is to create a saved UNION query named [SometingDataForPieChart]...

```
SELECT "DONE" AS PieCategory, [DONE] AS PieValue, [AREA] FROM [TABLE]
UNION ALL
SELECT "REMAIN" AS PieCategory, [REMAIN] AS PieValue, [AREA] FROM [TABLE]
```

...returning...

```
PieCategory | PieValue | AREA 
----------- | -------- | -----
DONE        |      100 | AREA1
DONE        |      200 | AREA2
DONE        |      200 | AREA3
REMAIN      |      200 | AREA1
REMAIN      |      300 | AREA2
REMAIN      |      700 | AREA3
```

...and this is how you start to do pie chart.

Please read [How to add a pie chart to my Access report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19327449/1380867) as it has many images and step by steps.

Credit to: [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) for this answer